# How to add custom template in Geany?

Tags: templates, ide, geany

How can I load my custom template in *Geany*? Or edit the exiting ones?

Is there  any wild-card or tag to load dates, names automatically?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Paste your custom template file in `~/.config/geany/templates/files/` directory. Then the template file can be loaded through **File -> New (With Template) -> pasted_file_name.ext**

See the picture (as picture *simple_skeleton.cpp* file is pasted to the directory)

[image: Geany custom template load]

Wildcards can be used such as {date}, {developer}.
See more: [Geany Templates](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#templates/)